MySQL: Is there a way to append a count to a concatenated field for duplicate entries?
One of the requirements for my final project is to create a list of email addresses for existing database entries. The email addresses are based off of the first and last name with the following convention:
First letter of [first_name][last_name] + @company.net in all lowercase.
The next part is to account for any duplicates that might arise. If there are two users, [John] [Miller] and [Jake] [Miller], they end up with the same email address: jmiller@company.net. I am supposed to append a sequential count to the email address for all duplicates. In this case, [Jake] [Miller] would have the email address: jmiller1@company.net.
I've been having some issues with this though. Is there a way to append a sequential count to the different users?
I have been able to achieve this with this query:
UPDATE employees_test 
SET 
    email = CONCAT(LOWER(SUBSTRING(first_name, 1, 1)),
            LOWER(last_name),
            '@company.net')
WHERE email IS NULL;

# emp_no  birth_date  first_name last_name gender hire_date    email
10001      1953-09-02    Georgi      Facello      M   1986-06-26     gfacello@company.net
10002      1964-06-02    Bezalel     Simmel       F   1985-11-21     bsimmel@company.net
10003      1959-12-03    Parto       Bamford      M   1986-08-28     pbamford@company.net


Assuming you're using MySQL 8.x, you can use the RANK() window function for this.

If there are two users, [John] [Miller] and [Jake] [Miller], they end up with the same email address: jmiller@company.net. I am supposed to append a sequential count to the email address for all duplicates. In this case, [Jake] [Miller] would have the email address: jmiller1@company.net. Imagine that there is 3rd Miller - Jane Miller, and her name was saved with a misprint as "Miller1"...

@Barmar,sir, why do we use rank() function ? I thought row_number() would be more appropriate , as  row_number() over (partition by duplicates) generates distinguish numbers for each member in a duplicate group.

What's the process here? You seem to be inserting and at a later point updating. If so then another approach may be to do the update in a stored procedure which would allow you to check existence before update.

@blabla_bingo I think either would work, since they both generate incrementing numbers.

If you are using mysql 8, we can use the row_number() window function to generate a incremental number for each duplicate. Check the demonstration below:
create table test(emp_no serial, first_name varchar(20),last_name varchar(20),email varchar(50));

alter table test auto_increment 10001;

insert test values 
(default,'john','miller',default),
(default,'terry','smith',default),
(default,'jane','miller',default),
(default,'sharon','redfield',default),
(default,'tim','smith',default),
(default,'jimmy','miller',default)
;

select * from test;
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
| emp_no | first_name | last_name | email |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+
|  10001 | john       | miller    | NULL  |
|  10002 | terry      | smith     | NULL  |
|  10003 | jane       | miller    | NULL  |
|  10004 | sharon     | redfield  | NULL  |
|  10005 | tim        | smith     | NULL  |
|  10006 | jimmy      | miller    | NULL  |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------+

As we can see from our test sample, based on our email's formula, there is going to be 3 jmiller and 2 tsmith. We shall use row_number() to address the duplicates. Here is the UPDATE statement to accomplish the job.
with cte as (
select emp_no,
lower(concat(substring(first_name,1,1),last_name)) as email_prefix,
row_number() over (partition by lower(concat(substring(first_name,1,1),last_name)) order by emp_no) as row_num
from test
)
update test t join cte c using(emp_no) 
set t.email = concat(email_prefix,case row_num when 1 then '' else row_num-1 end,'@company.net') 
where t.email is null
;

select * from test;
+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| emp_no | first_name | last_name | email                 |
+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  10001 | john       | miller    | jmiller@company.net   |
|  10002 | terry      | smith     | tsmith@company.net    |
|  10003 | jane       | miller    | jmiller1@company.net  |
|  10004 | sharon     | redfield  | sredfield@company.net |
|  10005 | tim        | smith     | tsmith1@company.net   |
|  10006 | jimmy      | miller    | jmiller2@company.net  |
+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+

Note, as Akina said, if a user's last name is mistakenly entered and happens to end with a number, it might cause email address conflicts. So we should add a check constraint in our table if it's available. (check constraint works since MySQL 8.0.16):
create table test(emp_no serial, first_name varchar(20),last_name varchar(20),email varchar(50),
check (last_name not regexp '[0-9]$'));

Now the check constraint disallows the last_name to have a trailing number.
insert test values  (default,'juliet','miller4',default);
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'test_chk_1' is violated. 

IMPORTANT 
Now let's think about this. Is the formula of appending a number based on the count of duplicates for the email address really appropriate ? For starters, it works without fail. But what about later on when a duplicate leaves, and a new duplicate joins ? How do we assign the number? Do we reuse the old one , or set it to max+1? Whatever we choose to do, the job is troublesome and prone to faults. e.g. If an old email address is reused for a new user, the user might receive a mail which is supposed to address the old user. And should we decide to use the max+1 as the number, that will leave a gap in the range. Then what's the meaning to use duplicate count as identifier if the number does not accurately reflects the actual count? 
With that being said, I suppose we can use a different formula to identify the duplicates. That's to use an identifier which is not prone to changes. And the emp_no fits the job. By using this method, when a duplicate is detected, instead of calculating the count of duplicates which requires a window function to ease the pain, adding a unique emp_no is more straightforward and stable.

Thank you! That was exactly what I needed!
